# Different Histogram Plots by Species, Site, and Date

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, histogram, lapply

I am trying to make a grid of plots for data like that below. There are 5 sites, 4 species, and 5 collection periods. I need a size frequency histogram for Mass for each site, date, species group. I.e. 260 plots. I've been playing with split, lapply, cut() and aggregate() as well as pipes in dplyr, but can't seem to find anything that does this pretty cleanly.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
newdata = split(data, list(data$Species,data$Site,data$Date))
histograms = lapply(newdata, function(x) {
histograms = hist(x$Mass, w=.1)
return(histograms)    
})
```

or subsetting out one species and one site:

```
infrequens = data[which(data$Species =='infrequens' & data$Site == '1'), ]

ggplot(gather(infrequens), aes(Mass)) + 
geom_histogram(binwidth = .1) + 
facet_wrap(~Date, scales = 'free_x')
```

but keep getting erros about bin length. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Site  Date         Species BodySize  Mass

```
1   0017-03-19  grandis  7.4    2.0555241       
2   0017-04-19  grandis  7.6    2.2167792       
1   0017-03-19  grandis  6.6    1.4866433       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii  8.2    2.7490281   
4   0017-04-19  doddsii  7.0    1.7562082       
3   0017-05-19  doddsii  7.8    2.3859990       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.8    2.3859990       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.6    2.2167792   
5   0017-03-19  doddsii  9.0    3.5782702   
5   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.2    1.9020590
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.2 0.4133332       
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.2 0.4133332       
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.6 0.5347965       
2   0017-04-19  infrequens  4.8 0.6033003       
2   0017-05-19  infrequens  6.2 1.2454079       
4   0017-04-19  infrequens  6.8 1.6177954       
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.0 0.3599915   
2   0017-02-19  infrequens  6.0 1.1349656
3   0017-04-19  cockerelli  12.0    6.4860992       
4   0017-02-19  cockerelli  11.8    6.1838799       
1   0017-03-19  cockerelli  10.8    4.8092579       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii     7.6     2.2167792
5   0017-03-19  grandis  7.4    2.0555241       
2   0017-04-19  grandis  7.6    2.2167792       
1   0017-03-19  grandis  6.6    1.4866433       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii  8.2    2.7490281   
4   0017-04-19  doddsii  7.0    1.7562082       
3   0017-05-19  doddsii  7.8    2.3859990       
5   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.8    2.3859990       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.6    2.2167792   
5   0017-03-19  doddsii  9.0    3.5782702   
5   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.2    1.9020590
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.2 0.4133332       
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.2 0.4133332       
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.6 0.5347965       
2   0017-04-19  infrequens  4.8 0.6033003       
2   0017-05-19  infrequens  6.2 1.2454079       
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  6.8 1.6177954       
2   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.0 0.3599915   
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  6.0 1.1349656
3   0017-04-19  cockerelli  12.0    6.4860992       
4   0017-02-19  cockerelli  11.8    6.1838799       
1   0017-03-19  cockerelli  10.8    4.8092579       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii     7.6     2.2167792
1   0017-03-19  grandis  7.4    2.0555241       
2   0017-04-19  grandis  7.6    2.2167792       
1   0017-03-19  grandis  6.6    1.4866433       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii  8.2    2.7490281   
4   0017-04-19  doddsii  7.0    1.7562082       
3   0017-05-19  doddsii  7.8    2.3859990       
1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.8    2.3859990       
3   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.6    2.2167792   
5   0017-03-19  doddsii  9.0    3.5782702   
5   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.2    1.9020590
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.2 0.4133332       
3   0017-04-19  infrequens  4.2 0.4133332       
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.6 0.5347965       
2   0017-04-19  infrequens  4.8 0.6033003       
2   0017-05-19  infrequens  6.2 1.2454079       
5   0017-02-19  infrequens  6.8 1.6177954       
5   0017-04-19  infrequens  4.0 0.3599915   
1   0017-03-19  infrequens  6.0 1.1349656
3   0017-04-19  cockerelli  12.0    6.4860992       
4   0017-02-19  cockerelli  11.8    6.1838799       
1   0017-03-19  cockerelli  10.8    4.8092579       
2   0017-03-19  doddsii     7.6     2.2167792
```

Comment: *"There are 5 sites, 5 species, and 5 collection periods"* Unfortunately your sample data has only **one site, one species and one date**. Can you please provide more **representative** sample data? Your code is also not reproducible. What is `infrequens`? You're also (probably) not using `tidyr::gather` correctly.

Comment: Hi Maurits, I've made some data additions and edits. Maybe that helps clear things up? Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Thanks that's better (although you still only have one date and site). Please take a look at my post below. Hopefully this should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(Mass, fill = Species)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1) +
    facet_grid(Date ~ Site, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Site Date Species BodySize Mass
    1   0017-03-19  grandis  7.4    2.0555241
    1   0017-03-19  grandis  7.6    2.2167792
    1   0017-03-19  grandis  6.6    1.4866433
    1   0017-03-19  doddsii  8.2    2.7490281
    1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.0    1.7562082
    1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.8    2.3859990
    1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.8    2.3859990
    1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.6    2.2167792
    1   0017-03-19  doddsii  9.0    3.5782702
    1   0017-03-19  doddsii  7.2    1.9020590
    1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.2 0.4133332
    1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.2 0.4133332
    1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.6 0.5347965
    1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.8 0.6033003
    1   0017-03-19  infrequens  6.2 1.2454079
    1   0017-03-19  infrequens  6.8 1.6177954
    1   0017-03-19  infrequens  4.0 0.3599915
    1   0017-03-19  infrequens  6.0 1.1349656
    1   0017-03-19  cockerelli  12.0    6.4860992
    1   0017-03-19  cockerelli  11.8    6.1838799
    1   0017-03-19  cockerelli  10.8    4.8092579
    1   0017-03-19  doddsii     7.6     2.2167792", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank Maurits! That is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @user9357993 Great, glad it helped:-)

Comment: This ended up being my final code:               

> newdata = split(data, list(data$Species,data$Site))                  

>plots = lapply(newdata, function(x){
 plots = ggplot(x, aes(Mass, fill = Species)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1) +
    facet_grid(Date ~ Site, scales = "free_x") + blankggplot + theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
  print(plots)
})